# How to delete Image saved on Firestorage inside a login area in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a registration area in which the user can choose a profile picture, among other things. If the user does not like the picture, the user has the option of removing the existing picture and inserting a new one. The Url of the picture in Firestore is deleted and replaced with the new Url. In addition, of course, the image should also be deleted from the Firestore Storage and replaced with the new one. Unfortunately, only a new picture is inserted here, so that the user has 2 profile pictures.

This is my method. I know that the run gives me an error message. However, I cannot interpret them at all, or I do not understand them.

```
void _deleteImage() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    String imgUrl;
    DocumentReference documentReference =
        Firestore.instance.collection("Users").document(user.uid);

    await documentReference.get().then((snapshot) {
      imgUrl = snapshot.data['Pictures'].toString();
    });
    print("This is the imgUrl: " + imgUrl);
    StorageReference _ref =
        await FirebaseStorage.instance.getReferenceFromUrl(imgUrl);
    await _ref.delete();
}

void _deleteUrl() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .document(user.uid)
        .updateData({"Pictures": FieldValue.delete()});
}
```

This is the Run:

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri could not be parsed.
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(FirebaseStorage.java:265)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage.FirebaseStoragePlugin.getReferenceFromUrl(FirebaseStoragePlugin.java:172)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage.FirebaseStoragePlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseStoragePlugin.java:102)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:379)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage( 8724):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
E/flutter ( 8724): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, The storage Uri could not be parsed., null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri could not be parsed.
E/flutter ( 8724):  at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(FirebaseStorage.java:265)
E/flutter ( 8724):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage.FirebaseStoragePlugin.getReferenceFromUrl(FirebaseStoragePlugin.java:172)
E/flutter ( 8724):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage.FirebaseStoragePlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseStoragePlugin.java:102)
E/flutter ( 8724):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter ( 8724):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter ( 8724):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/flutter ( 8724):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 8724):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:379)
E/flutter ( 8724):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
E/flutter ( 8724):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
E/flutter ( 8724):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 8724):  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
E/flutter ( 8724):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Maybe that can help. I found out that the following part of the code is causing the error:

```
 StorageReference _ref =
        await FirebaseStorage.instance.getReferenceFromUrl(imgUrl);
    await _ref.delete();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time coding, I finally came up with a solution. A list is required in which the url of the image is saved. The list is then simply cleaned up in the deleteImage method. :)

```
List loginImageUrl = [];


FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await Firestore.instance
                                          .collection("Users")
                                          .document(user.uid)
                                          .get();

                                  if (documentSnapshot.data['Pictures'] !=
                                      null) {
                                    loginImageUrl.insert(
                                        0,
                                        documentSnapshot.data['Pictures']
                                            [0]);

                                    await _deleteImage();
                                    await _deleteUrl();

_deleteImage() async {
if (loginImageUrl[0] != null) {
  StorageReference storageReference =
      await FirebaseStorage.instance.getReferenceFromUrl(loginImageUrl[0]);
  storageReference.delete();
  loginImageUrl.clear();
}
}

_deleteUrl() async {
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
await Firestore.instance
    .collection("Users")
    .document(user.uid)
    .updateData({"Pictures": FieldValue.delete()});
}
```

So I do not know how to format the code here, but this is all I did. It is very simple. I just define the List. Than I have my two functions, which are used to delete the URL from firestore and the the hole image from Storage by its URL stored on firestore. I get exis of this functions just on a butten press.

If something is not clear, just ask, I try to explain it better. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't code flutter, however your problem is most likely related to the `_deleteUrl()` function updating the user's picture object with FieldValue.delete(). I would recommend setting it to a default image or prompting the user to submit a new image to replace the deleted one. However, I might be misunderstanding the issue. If you could show more code we could better help.

Also, what stands out to me is the following runtime error message:
`Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, The storage Uri could not be parsed., null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri could not be parsed.`

To me that suggests that your `_deleteImage()` function is having problems when requesting the URL from firebase. I would recommend looking at the documentation to see what is going wrong with requesting the URL: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The funny thing is, if I enter the url by hand, it works fine. If I output the url with print, I also have no problems. But with the method as above, it gives me this error. I know the _deleteImage method is the problem, but I don't understand the logic behind it. The functions work wonderfully individually, but not together.